# "Call to Node module failed with error"s with Angular2 & ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, angular

I'm getting an intermittent exception with my ASP.NET Core Angular 2 web-app:

```
Exception: Call to Node module failed with error: Error: This method is not implemented in Parse5DomAdapter: Parse5DomAdapter#getCookie
 at _notImplemented (D:\Projects\MyProject\MyProject\node_modules\angular2-platform-node\parse5-adapter.js:22:12)
 at Parse5DomAdapter.getCookie (D:\Projects\MyProject\MyProject\node_modules\angular2-platform-node\parse5-adapter.js:641:15)
 at CookieXSRFStrategy.configureRequest (D:\Projects\MyProject\MyProject\node_modules\@angular\http\bundles\http.umd.js:1597:92)
 at XHRBackend.createConnection (D:\Projects\MyProject\MyProject\node_modules\@angular\http\bundles\http.umd.js:1637:32)
 at httpRequest (D:\Projects\MyProject\MyProject\node_modules\@angular\http\bundles\http.umd.js:1975:24)
 at Http.get (D:\Projects\MyProject\MyProject\node_modules\@angular\http\bundles\http.umd.js:2086:20)
 at ApiService.getChatMessages (D:\Projects\MyProject\MyProject\ClientApp\dist\main-server.js:557:20)
 at ChatPageComponent.ngOnInit (D:\Projects\MyProject\MyProject\ClientApp\dist\main-server.js:513:23)
 at AppView._View_ChatPageComponent_Host0.detectChangesInternal (ChatPageComponent_Host.ngfactory.js:30:86)
 at AppView.detectChanges (D:\Projects\MyProject\MyProject\node_modules\@angular\core\bundles\core.umd.js:9566:18)

MoveNext
```

I believe it's something to do with the MVC views, as the error shows:

```
MoveNext in Index.cshtml

1.@{
2.    ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
3.}
4.
5.<app asp-prerender-module="ClientApp/dist/main-server">Loading...</app>
6.
7.<script src="~/dist/vendor.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
8.@section scripts {
```

Which is code in my index.cshtml.

It seems to happen early on after launching the project. It all either works fine, or after loading the home page when any navagation is performed it throws an error.

I can force it to produce the error. I have 4 navagation destinations:

```
http://localhost:49954/home
http://localhost:49954/counter
http://localhost:49954/fetch-data
http://localhost:49954/chat-page
```

That were all set up from the Visual Studio Angular 2 template. If I refresh home, everything is fine, and if it's had a chance to load for a while I can navagate to the other pages. However if I type in the url for any of the other pages, it produces this error every single time.

Edit: Also, interestingly, it produces a slightly different error with `http://localhost:49954/counter`. In my counter page I use an Angular Material Design component:

```
<div class="mine">
    <h2>
        Counter Test
    </h2>
    <p>This is a simple example of an Angular 2 component.</p>
    <p>Current count:<strong>{{ currentCount }}</strong></p>
    <button md-raised-button (click)="incrementCounter()">Increment</button>
</div>
```

and instead of the above error, it's a similar Call to Node module failed error, but in material design:

```
Exception: Call to Node module failed with error: Error: Uncaught (in promise): ReferenceError: document is not defined
 ReferenceError: document is not defined
 at new RippleRenderer (D:\Projects\MyProject\MyProject\node_modules\@angular\material\material.umd.js:193:31)
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This worked for me. Change:

```
<app asp-prerender-module="ClientApp/dist/main-server">Loading...</app>
```

to

```
<app asp-ng2-prerender-module="ClientApp/dist/main-server">Loading...</app>
```

in the index.html

Comment: I am having hard time finding any documentation on asp-ng2-prerender-module. What exactly does it do? And is there any bad side effects of it?

Answer (score 15):

**Edit:** A few months later, and this is pretty out of date and there's a better solution posted by Jimmy. So moving the "correct" marker to his answer.

It seems to be an issue with the pre-rendering as Angular 2 Material is incompatible with Angular Universal.

I changed:

```
<app asp-prerender-module="ClientApp/dist/main-server">Loading...</app>
```

to:

```
<app class="container" style="display: block;">Loading...</app>
```

in the index.cshtml and it functions fine now (with a "Loading..." untill fully loaded).

Comment: nice catch :) ,

Comment: Are you sure that this is the solution? What happens to the code in the main-server.ts file? Aren't you bypassing this? This removed my error but what happens now that the main-server module is removed? Thanks

Comment: Are you using any templates? I'm using this: http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2016/10/04/angular2-template-for-visual-studio/.

You're right. It's not really a solution. And yes, the not working main-server.js is still compiled by the Webpack (in the above template), just not used by the site. I was getting the error because angular material 2 isn't compatible with angular universal and can't be compiled on the server and provide a pre-rendered site.

Comment: Various discussions on Material's incompatibility here: https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/308. There may be some better workarounds. Currently I'm using MaterialDesign Lite and it works fine with pre-rendering - something I think is important for SEO

Comment: I am using the same template.   I was trying to integrate Dan Whalin's Customer Manager pages into the application generated by this template. https://github.com/DanWahlin/Angular2-JumpStart

Comment: Oh..really nice.Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Had the same issue with `yo aspnetcore-spa` Angular2 app and `npm i --save auth0-lock` from npm very much obliged for this though I guess you sacrifice the prerendering - hopefully it will get sorted so they work in tandem at some point but this is great for now.

Answer (score 3):

To be a little more clear, edit Views/Home/index.html and change the following line:

```
<app asp-prerender-module="ClientApp/dist/main-server">Loading...</app>
```

to the following

```
<app asp-ng2-prerender-module="ClientApp/dist/main-server">Loading...</app>
```

Comment: Do you mind if I combine this with Jimmy's answer, as it's the same thing but clearer?

Comment: Sure no problem