# Adding Dragular to Angular2 Application: document is not defined

Tags: asp.net, angular, webpack, dragula

I am fairly new to Angular2 and I am having issues adding Dragula to my application. When I run the application an error is thrown prior to loading the home page:

```
Exception: Call to Node module failed with error: Prerendering failed because of error: ReferenceError: document is not defined
```

The error message mentions Prerending which I suspect is in relation to the project using `asp-prerender-module`.

I've tried to follow official tutorials from Dragula and forum posts. Below are my app.module and component file snippets (... denotes summarised code):

**app.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { UniversalModule } from 'angular2-universal';
import { AppComponent } from './components/app/app.component'
...
import { SearchComponent } from './components/search/search.component';

import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { DragulaModule } from 'ng2-dragula';


@NgModule({
    bootstrap: [ AppComponent ],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        ...
        SearchComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        UniversalModule,
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,
        DragulaModule,
        CommonModule,
        RouterModule.forRoot([
            { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
            ...
            { path: 'search', component: SearchComponent },
            { path: '**', redirectTo: 'home' }
        ])
    ]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

**search.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { SearchService } from '../../services/search.service';
import { DragulaService } from 'ng2-dragula';

@Component({
    selector: 'search',
    template: require('./search.component.html'),
    providers: [SearchService, DragulaService]
})
```

I suspect I am missing an a step when including Dragula, but I cannot figure out where. I have included both *dragula (^3.7.2)* and *ng2-dragula (^1.3.0)* in my package.json file.

Comment: Have you resolved this issue already? I have the same problem with ng2-dragula module.

Comment: I found fix for this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40257514/call-to-node-module-failed-with-errors-with-angular2-asp-net

Answer (score 0):

your DragulaService initialization is wrong!!  check Dragula documentation  [link](https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-dragula#usage)

**search.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { SearchService } from '../../services/search.service';
import { DragulaService } from 'ng2-dragula';

@Component({
    selector: 'search',
    template: require('./search.component.html'),
    providers: [SearchService]
})

expoert searchcomponent{
constructor(private dragulaService: DragulaService) {
        console.log('DragulaService created');
}
}
```

Now you can play with drag and drop

If you want more control over drag and drop you can add events and options to dragulaService.

```
constructor(private dragulaService: DragulaService) {
    dragulaService.drag.subscribe((value) => {
      console.log(`drag: ${value[0]}`);
      this.onDrag(value.slice(1));
    });
    dragulaService.drop.subscribe((value) => {
      console.log(`drop: ${value[0]}`);
      this.onDrop(value.slice(1));
    });
    dragulaService.over.subscribe((value) => {
      console.log(`over: ${value[0]}`);
      this.onOver(value.slice(1));
    });
    dragulaService.out.subscribe((value) => {
      console.log(`out: ${value[0]}`);
      this.onOut(value.slice(1));
    });
  }

  private onDrag(args) {
    let [e, el] = args;
    // do something
  }

  private onDrop(args) {
    let [e, el] = args;
    // do something
  }

  private onOver(args) {
    let [e, el, container] = args;
    // do something
  }

  private onOut(args) {
    let [e, el, container] = args;
    // do something
  }
```