# Using semantic ui with webpack on the Asp.Net Core Spa template

Tags: angular, webpack, asp.net-core, semantic-ui

I'm trying to use Semantic UI with Angular 2 over Asp.Net Core. I've started with the `aspnetcore-spa` project template from the [JavaScript services](https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices) official Yeoman templates which already has Asp.Net MVC Core, Webpack, Angular 2 and Bootstrap configured.

Then, I tried following the steps described on [this GitHub](https://github.com/cbeulke/tutorial-angular2-webpack-semantic) to install Semantic UI.

The steps I did:

- Installed Semantic UI using NPM `npm install semantic-ui --save`

  - During the setup, I installed all the features and selected the install folder as `wwwroot/lib/semantic/`
- Went to the `wwwroot/lib/semantic` folder and ran `gulp build`

That's where I started to be really unsure, in the template structure there's no `vendor.ts`, so I was not really sure where to put the import for the Semantic css and js.

The only thing I could find was the `webpack.config.vendor.js` that contained some entries for Bootstrap, so I modified the `vendor` property and added the import for the semantic js and css.

Here's how I modified it:

```
entry: {
    vendor: [
        '@angular/common',
        '@angular/compiler',
        '@angular/core',
        '@angular/http',
        '@angular/platform-browser',
        '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic',
        '@angular/router',
        '@angular/platform-server',
        'angular2-universal',
        'angular2-universal-polyfills',
        'es6-shim',
        'es6-promise',
        'event-source-polyfill',
        'jquery',
        'zone.js',
        'wwwroot/lib/semantic/dist/semantic.min.js',
        'wwwroot/lib/semantic/dist/semantic.min.css',
        'ng-semantic'
    ]
}
```

I removed the references to bootstrap and added `semantic.min.js`, `semantic.min.css`, and `ng-semantic`.

Finally, I installed `Ng-Semantic` using NPM and added `import { NgSemanticModule } from 'ng-semantic'` into `app.module.ts`.

Now, when I try to run the application, I get the following error:

> System.Exception: Call to Node module failed with error: Prerendering
>   failed because of error: ReferenceError: jQuery is  not defined

I get that this error is caused by the system trying to pre-render some code that rely on jQuery which is a big no-no and it's probably the semantic-ui.js. But I have absolutely no idea how that could be fixed.

For reference and easier troubleshooting, I've pushed the current status of the code to GitHub, it's available at [this address](https://github.com/Gimly/dotnetcore-spa-semantic-ui).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try removing `app-prerenderer-module` attribute https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40257514/call-to-node-module-failed-with-errors-with-angular2-asp-net

Comment: Well, sure removing the pre-rendering will definitely fix the issue, but I wanted a solution where I could keep the pre-rendering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to make it work correctly, thanks in part to this other SO question: [asp.net core spa template, Semantic UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45290969/asp-net-core-spa-template-semantic-ui)

I'm copying the steps proposed in the question here, for simplicity and adding a few comments.

- First, the idea is to install just the CSS for Semantic UI using NPM:

  - `npm install semantic-ui-css --save`
- Then, install the [ng2-semantic-ui](https://github.com/edcarroll/ng2-semantic-ui) library. It allows to use all the Semantic UI components without dependency to JQuery.

  - `npm install ng2-semantic-ui --save`
- Open the `webpack.config.vendor.js` file, remove `bootstrap` and `bootstrap.css` in entry/vendor list and replace them by `'ng2-semantic-ui'` and `'semantic-ui-css/semantic.css'`
- Rebuild the `vendor.js` using the command

  - `webpack --config webpack.config.vendor.js` if you have webpack installed globally
  - or `node node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --config webpack.config.vendor.js --env.prod` if you don't
- Import `SuiModule` from `ng2-semantic-ui`in the `app.module.client.ts` file.
- Finally, on the .Net side, in `Views/Home/Index.html`, replace `asp-prerender-module` by `asp-ng2-prerender-module` and the "Loading..." by the following:

  `<div class="ui active inverted dimmer">
      <div class="ui text large loader">Loading</div>
  </div>`

Then, you have to rewrite a lot of the app to replace the bootstrap css classes by Semantic UI's.