# Angular Material setup with BrowserAnimationsModule for Angular 4.4.6 app

Tags: angular-material

I am trying to get angular material working in my angular 4.4.6 app but get an error message in the browser when I try to import the  BrowserAnimationsModule.

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

imports: [
    CommonModule,
    HttpModule,
    FormsModule, 
    AngularFontAwesomeModule,
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot([  
        { path: 'register', component: RegisterComponent },
        { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
        { path: 'member-detail/:id', component: MemberDetailComponent },
        { path: 'member-listing', component: MemberListingComponent },
```

---

package.json

"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^4.4.6",
    "@angular/cdk": "^2.0.0-beta.12",
    "@angular/common": "^4.4.6",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.4.6",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.4.6",
    "@angular/core": "^4.4.6",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.4.6",
    "@angular/http": "^4.4.6",
    "@angular/material": "^2.0.0-beta.12",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.4.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.4.6",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^4.4.6",

---

Error message in browser:

An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.

NodeInvocationException: document is not defined
ReferenceError: document is not defined
at DefaultDomRenderer2.module.exports.DefaultDomRenderer2.selectRootElement (C:\Code\winowio_core\winowio_core\Client\dist\vendor.js:28722:72)
at BaseAnimationRenderer.selectRootElement (C:\Code\winowio_core\winowio_core\Client\dist\main-server.js:19174:106)
at createElement (C:\Code\winowio_core\winowio_core\Client\dist\vendor.js:20127:23)
at createViewNodes (C:\Code\winowio_core\winowio_core\Client\dist\vendor.js:23093:44)
at createRootView (C:\Code\winowio_core\winowio_core\Client\dist\vendor.js:23022:5)
at Object.createProdRootView [as createRootView] (C:\Code\winowio_core\winowio_core\Client\dist\vendor.js:23707:12)
at ComponentFactory_.module.exports.ComponentFactory_.create (C:\Code\winowio_core\winowio_core\Client\dist\vendor.js:20813:46)
at ComponentFactoryBoundToModule.module.exports.ComponentFactoryBoundToModule.create (C:\Code\winowio_core\winowio_core\Client\dist\vendor.js:14230:29)
at ApplicationRef_.module.exports.ApplicationRef_.bootstrap (C:\Code\winowio_core\winowio_core\Client\dist\vendor.js:15719:57)
at C:\Code\winowio_core\winowio_core\Client\dist\vendor.js:15502:81
Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices.HostingModels.HttpNodeInstance+d__7.MoveNext()

Stack Query Cookies Headers
NodeInvocationException: document is not defined
 ReferenceError: document is not defined at DefaultDomRenderer2.module.exports.DefaultDomRenderer2.selectRootElement (C:\Code\winowio_core\winowio_core\Client\dist\vendor.js:28722:72) at BaseAnimationRenderer.selectRootElement (C:\Code\winowio_core\winowio_core\Client\dist\main-server.js:19174:106) at createElement (C:\Code\winowio_core\winowio_core\Client\dist\vendor.js:20127:23) at createViewNodes (C:\Code\winowio_core\winowio_core\Client\dist\vendor.js:23093:44) at createRootView (C:\Code\winowio_core\winowio_core\Client\dist\vendor.js:23022:5) at Object.createProdRootView [as createRootView] (C:\Code\winowio_core\winowio_core\Client\dist\vendor.js:23707:12) at ComponentFactory_.module.exports.ComponentFactory_.create (C:\Code\winowio_core\winowio_core\Client\dist\vendor.js:20813:46) at ComponentFactoryBoundToModule.module.exports.ComponentFactoryBoundToModule.create (C:\Code\winowio_core\winowio_core\Client\dist\vendor.js:14230:29) at ApplicationRef_.module.exports.ApplicationRef_.bootstrap (C:\Code\winowio_core\winowio_core\Client\dist\vendor.js:15719:57) at C:\Code\winowio_core\winowio_core\Client\dist\vendor.js:15502:81
Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices.HostingModels.HttpNodeInstance+d__7.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices.HostingModels.OutOfProcessNodeInstance+d__13.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices.NodeServicesImpl+d__10.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices.NodeServicesImpl+d__10.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices.NodeServicesImpl+d__10.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Prerendering.PrerenderTagHelper+d__29.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Runtime.TagHelpers.TagHelperRunner+d__0.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
AspNetCore._Views_Home_Index_cshtml+d__12.MoveNext() in Index.cshtml
+
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView+d__16.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView+d__15.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView+d__14.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewExecutor+d__22.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewExecutor+d__21.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewResult+d__26.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker+d__19.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker+d__24.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResultExecutedContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Next(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker+d__22.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Next(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker+d__17.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker+d__15.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware+d__4.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware+d__6.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Webpack.ConditionalProxyMiddleware+d__6.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Webpack.ConditionalProxyMiddleware+d__6.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware+d__7.MoveNext()

Comment: Can you please post your whole code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I came to this same exact issue.

Go to Views->Home->Index.cshtml and change

```
<app asp-prerender-module="ClientApp/dist/main-server">Loading...</app>
```

to:

```
<app asp-ng2-prerender-module="ClientApp/dist/main-server">Loading...</app>
```

Here is another [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40257514/call-to-node-module-failed-with-errors-with-angular2-asp-net/43156166#43156166) question that's related.